# how to make a URL fetch then return immediately

Tags: java, google-app-engine, asynchronous, urlfetch

is it possible for a java appengine servlet to make a simple URL fetch (async) and then return immediately.

I do not need the response of the url fetch and thus want to return as soon as the url fetch is initated. If I return from a servlet does my request handler wait for the async url fetch to complete (and thus there are no savings) or will my request handler complete and the URL fetch complete?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, just don't check the result.